# How can I use VS2008 to build a project like this?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I am writing a C++ project
The VS2008 does not give me directory like src/bin/data... I would these folder, which src folder store the source, and bin folder store the program.

How can it be done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS doesn't need the source files in any particular dir structure, you can have it produce the output in Debug and Release directories if you want, it's all set in the properties dialogs.

The easiest thing is to create a new empty project and then copy your code into the same directory as the main.cpp that will be created.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the project's "Intermediate" and "Output" directories by going to Project Settings | General.  Output Directory and Intermediate Directory are the first two options.

Comment: doesn't work. it only output the whole bunch of things into that folder. I would it to pack the source file as well.

Comment: @gunbuster363 You can put your source files anywhere you want, VS doesn't care.  You can also set the intermediate and output directories to whatever you want.  If you only want to move your final binary somewhere, use a custom post-build event.

Comment: Remember if you move the source files you have to remove and then re-add them to the file list inside the IDE (add existing item)